I can`t see menu on mobile in wordpress
The WordPress mobile menu appears in the editing section, but it doesn't show up on the site in mobile view.[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/XIqffGIc.png)
I couldn't set it as primary because the option didn't appear in the Menus section. Besides that, I don't have much knowledge about WordPress, could you please help me?
